# How to force an element to "go to top" if there is no more height in parent element?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 6 s inside a parent 
The height of the internal divs change dynamically based on the underlying data.
The outer Div has a set height.
What I want is that when one of the internal Divs no longer fit (heightwise) in the parent that it should just move over to a "new column" inside the parent Div

Here is a short snippet with my situation:

```css
 #outer {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 96px;
  max-height: 96px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;

}

#outer div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div id="outer">
    <div>Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
    <div>Item3</div>
    <div>Item4</div>
    <div>Item5</div>
    <div>Item6</div>
  </div>
```

Here is another snippet of how I would want it to appear:

```css
 #outer {
 float:left;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 96px;
  max-height: 96px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;

}

#outer div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div id="outer">
    <div>Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
   <div>Item3</div>
   </div>
     <div id="outer">
   <div>Item4</div>
   <div>Item5</div>
   <div>Item6</div>
   
  </div>
```

Can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flex wrapping can easily solve this problem.

[If you're using bootstrap, you don't need to write the css written in '*' selector]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
  
#outer div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div>Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
    <div>Item3</div>
    <div>Item4</div>
    <div>Item5</div>
    <div>Item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote. What you did, would also work with a simple float. I need it to go down vertically 1 -> 2 -> 3 and then when it runs out of space, then 4 -> 5 ->6 in the second column. and it needs to support different heights without leaving any white spaces

Comment: I have solved my issue with  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    flex-direction: column;